# MATLAB str to cell (trivial ?)

Tags: string, matlab

I would like to make out of a big string a cell array, e.g. I have :

```
str1 = ['aa1','bb1','cc1'];
str2 = ['aa2','bb2','cc2'];
```

The question is how to make out of each comma separated string entry, seperate cell array entry. Im looking for something similar like

```
dataCell = {eval(str1),';', ...
            eval(str2)};
```

At the end I want to have the following :

```
dataCell = {'aa1','bb2','cc2'; 'aa2','bb2','cc2'}
```

I could have gone over loop and do something like

```
dataCell {end+1} = 'string';
```

but I wanted to do all at once, if possible.

Thanks in advance.

PS The question is which of all solutions it the best in terms of performance ?

Comment: `str1 = ['aa1','bb1','cc1'];` just concatenates the strings to `aa1bb1cc1`, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 4):

I like these kind of questions because it can show you all kinds of different ways to do the same thing:

```
str1=['aa1';'bb1';'cc1'];   
str2=['aa2';'bb2';'cc2'];  
data = [cellstr(str1) cellstr(str2)]'

data =     
    'aa1'    'bb1'    'cc1'
    'aa2'    'bb2'    'cc2'
```

Again this is assuming str1 and str2 are`;` separated.

Comment: The question is, which of the solutions it the best in terms of performance ?

Comment: Indeed there often are more ways to do one thing, and I think yours is simpler and more elegant.

Comment: @HeinrichStack I performed a `tic` `toc` around my code with a str1 and str2 that were each approximately 22000x3 char arrays.  Mine came in at 0.155s and Aabaz came in at 0.200s.  I did not try Itamar's answer as that was giving me a single column vector.  So speed probably is not an issue here.  Also I noticed in a comment that you wanted the transpose of this answer.  If so remove the `'` from the end of the `data =` line

Comment: I don't understand the question.  That would make str3 a single column with the values of str1&2 end to end.  What are you wanting to do with it ... ?

Comment: I have a big string, containing different rows for the cell array. The goal is to converted into a cell array

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, I would like to point out that `str=['aa1','bb1','cc1'];` is a char variable which is composed of the three strings concatenated (as opposed to `str=['aa1';'bb1';'cc1'];` which is a 3 by 1 char array).

Assuming that you meant to have a char array, then you can use the function [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/mat2cell.html) to build cell array from your char array:

```
str1=['aa1';'bb1';'cc1'];
str2=['aa2';'bb2';'cc2'];
dataCell1=mat2cell(str1,ones(1,size(str1,1)),size(str1,2));
dataCell2=mat2cell(str2,ones(1,size(str2,1)),size(str2,2));
dataCell=[dataCell1 dataCell2]';
```

Which gives you the following cell array:

```
'aa1'    'bb1'    'cc1'
'aa2'    'bb2'    'cc2'
```

**UPDATE**: as you seem concerned about performance, I ran a little test to compare the build time of a cell array from a n by n character array. This is not a precise benchmark but it gives interesting results.

```
n=5;
Elapsed time is 0.008 seconds for mat2cell.
Elapsed time is 0.002 seconds for cellstr
Elapsed time is 0.0003 seconds for the loop.
n=500;
Elapsed time is 0.015 seconds for mat2cell.
Elapsed time is 0.005 seconds for cellstr.
Elapsed time is 0.0015 seconds for the loop.
n=5000;
Elapsed time is 0.64 seconds for mat2cell.
Elapsed time is 0.20 seconds for cellstr.
Elapsed time is 0.16 seconds for the loop.
```

If you want to test it out (or correct my possible mistakes), here is how I did:

```
clear all;
n=500;
str=[repmat('a',1,n)];
strarray=repmat(str,n,1);
tic;
strcell=mat2cell(strarray,ones(1,size(strarray,1)),size(strarray,2));
toc;
clear all;
n=500;
str=[repmat('a',1,n)];
strarray=repmat(str,n,1);
tic;
strcell=cellstr(strarray);
toc;
clear all;
n=500;
str=[repmat('a',1,n)];
strarray=repmat(str,n,1);
tic;
strcell=cell(size(strarray,1),1);
for i=1:size(strarray,1)
   strcell{i}=strarray(i,:); 
end
toc;
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact I wanted the transposed of your answer.

Comment: In terms of performance, this solution would be quicker than just appending ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean

```
str1 = ['aa1';'bb1';'cc1'];
str2 = ['aa2';'bb2';'cc2'];
```

otherwise you just get a single vector for each variable.
in that case, you should use:

```
mat2cell([str1;str2],ones(1,6),3)
```